# android activities being launched repeatedly unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I have a simple button that launches a second activity, starts a spinner (If that's relevant) and does some http connection work. This second activity can also be launched by a service that runs and listens to a bluetooth connection.

The problem is not happening on my milestone (2.1-update1) phone but on a colleagues phone who is running 2.3 I believe. When they press the button to launch the second activity (Ignoring the service portion completely) it will launch the activity multiple times, when they press back on that second screen they land on another instance of that second screen instead of being back on the first activity.

I mention the service part of this for two reason, the first being that this problem started happening when I implemented the service, and the second being because I had a separate problem where the clients weren't being managed correctly on the service side so that when the second activity was being launched through the service instead of the button I would see exactly this behavior. Since the message was being sent to all clients (There should only be one) I was seeing the service spawn multiple launches of this second activity. But again by pressing the button this service problem which has been fixed shouldn't be responsible.

Now, I have put two things in place to prevent this from happening anymore. I have flagged the second activity as singleTask (android:launchMode="singleTask") and noticed that I had been launching the second activity as startActivityForResult, but wasn't setting or using that when it came back. This wasn't causing any errors or anything, but I changed it to a plain startActivity.

I do not have physical access to the other phone so I can't hook it up to logcat or anything, as it is in another office elsewhere.

The other phone isn't seeing the problem anymore but I am worried that I have hidden the problem rather than really fixing it, and was wondering if anyone could provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem before where different phones exhibited different symptoms when starting services. Some would restart (kill and start) the service multiple times and others would not. I'm taking a guess that because your friend's phone restarts the service multiple times somehow your activity is getting called each time it restarts.

Try this, can you show notifications in your service? If so do:

```
startForeground(ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

This makes the service always run in the foreground and it is less likely to be killed by android.

Comment: I do show notification in the service using that method, I was also using the setForeground(true); but logcat said it was ignoring it, I removed it anyway just in case. I don't believe the service is being killed though.